# AttributeError: partially initialized module 'boto3' has no attribute 'session' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python-3.x, boto3

I tried the below code

```
import boto3
aws_mg_con=boto3.session.Session(profile_name='demo_user')
iam_con=aws_mg_con.resource('iam')
```

But i receive this error

'AttributeError: partially initialized module 'boto3' has no attribute 'session' (most likely due to a circular import)'

I tried renaming the file, still same error is coming.

Need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a local file with the same name as 'boto3' , "Python sees the local file and thinks it's the module ".
Make sure the name of the file is not the same as the module

Comment: Hi, i tried renaming the file. But still same error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. The issue was, i saved the code with other name, but kept the first file as 'boto3.py'.
I deleted the old file, now the code is working.